# Tomcat REST API Path Size

Tags: java, rest, azure, tomcat

I have a Rest API running in Tomcat on Windows (in Azure). My path size is 346 bytes, this works fine when testing locally on the Windows server. When testing from an external machine the path size becomes a problem and fails.

If I drop the path down to 225 bytes or below it will work fine.

I've checked Tomcat server.xml for the header and path size limits which are not set therefore using default values.

Is there anything in Azure or Windows Server that would restrict the path size coming in externally?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be the Intrusion Protection Service on our firewall.